# Enable Wifi via batch file in Windows 10

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, batch

In Windows 10 a Wifi Adapter has a Software and a Hardware state. When I do

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

I get the following output. (Sorry my Windows is german)

```
...
Name                   : WiFi
Funkstatus           : Hardware Ein
                         Software Aus
```

It says Wifi State: Hardware On, Software Off

I can toggle the Software state with this GUI Interface
[Turning software Wifi State on and off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mup0.jpg)

I would like to change this "Software State" in a Batch file. Is there a command for it?

The command

```
netsh interface set interface "WiFi" enabled
```

does not work for this, because this to activate the whole Wifi Adapter. But the adapter is already enabled.

Comment: This does not answer my question I edited it to tell why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about straight batch, but Powershell can do this and then you could wrap it inside of batch code.

```
If ( (Get-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet').Status -ne 'Connected' )

    {

      Get-NetAdapter | Disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false -AsJob | Wait-Job 
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name 'Wi-Fi'-Confirm:$false

Enable-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet 3' -Confirm:$false
If ( (Get-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet').Status -ne 'Connected' )

    {

      Get-NetAdapter | Disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false -AsJob | Wait-Job

      Enable-NetAdapter -Name 'Wi-Fi'-Confirm:$false

      Enable-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet 3' -Confirm:$false

      }
```

Then you can use this to wrap it into batch

```
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Path\Script.ps1" "Parameter with spaces" Parameter2
```

I found most of this via google searches, but I've found that Powershell can automate a ton of simple Windows functions.